# I created a react project and I did routing. In routing I am struggling with syntax errors

Tags: reactjs

I created React project, In that project I created one folder and named it as a Pages. In the Pages folder I have one folder and Named it as Home, in that that Home folder I have Home.js and Home.css files. Again in the Pages Folder I have another folder and named it as Registration, in that  folder I have Registration.js and Registration.css. Once Again in Pages folder I have another folder and named it as Login in that folder I have Login.js and Login.css. 
I created another folder and named it as Components in that folder I have another folder Navbar. In Navbar folder I have Navbar.js and Navbar.css files.
Now I install react-router-dom  npm and did Routing but I am struggling with Syntax error please help me to solve this error.
The error is like this:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home';
import Login from './Pages/Login/Login';
import Registration from './Pages/Registration/Registration'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Switch>
          <Route path=''><Home></Home></Route>
          <Route path='/reg'><Registration></Registration></Route>
          <Route path='/log'><Login></Login></Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Navbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="www.facebook.com">Mern Stack</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        <li className="nav-item active">
                            <Link to='' className='nav-link'>Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to='/reg' className='nav-link'>Registration</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to='/log' className='nav-link'>Login</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

This is Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';


class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <h1>Home works</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

This is Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Login.css';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <h1>Login works</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

This is Registration.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Registration.css';


class Registration extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <h1>Registration works</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Registration
```

Comment: Could you please share also the Home, Login and Registration components?

Comment: Avoid default (or you might have forget to have default export) in home component and use 
````export Home````
and use
````import {Home} from './Pages/Home/Home';````

Comment: Hi @Girgetto I have written nothing in Home.js and Login.js and Registration.js all those files are empty.

Comment: That's the problem, you need to export atleast a dummy component from it

Comment: Hi @AjayGhosh, where I have to import { Home } from './Pages/Home/Home';

Comment: That it's up to you, the only thing is to take care to not use components that are not declared.

Comment: When was I am in Home page, it is showing Home works that's fine. But when I went to the Registration page on that page also it is showing Home Works, But It has to show Registration works but it not why?

Comment: Add a "/" at the beginning of your route, ex: `path="/reg"` `to="/reg"`

Comment: Hi @Girgetto, I tried what you said but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy Home Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>hai</div>
        )
    }
}

export Home
```

import this component in App component, Since this is not a default export, you need to specfic the name in the {} as follows

```
import {Home} from './Pages/Home/Home';
```

Comment: When was I am in Home page, it is showing Home works that's fine. But when I went to the Registration page on that page also it is showing Home Works, But It has to show Registration works but it not why?